# How does a piecewise step function work?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The wiki pages aren't helping at all.
What is a step function and how does it work?
I've seen them used in the floor, ceil, frac and even signum functions.
And although it is easy to understand what those functions do, their graphs are alien-looking thanks to the step functions. A brief explanation of how they're used in these cases might also be of help.

Edit: I apologize if I was a bit vague in my question.
[image]
[image]'[image]
**What exactly are these lines called, how do they work and how are they related to intervals?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try to be more specific about what you're asking?

Comment: Can you give and example of what you find strange?

Comment: @hhsaffar: Well, they sorta look like [intervals that I learnt in linear inequalities](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh6Wx.jpg)

And also, they look and act different [in the signum function](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e4vCl.png)

Comment: Do you have a problem understanding those little circles?

Comment: @hhsaffar: yes, exactly. But especially in the heaviside and signum functions. Also, $x+2$ can be expressed as $(x^2 - 4)/(x-2)$ bu this would cause it to not be defined at 2. We use these dot things like magnets or something when we have gaps like that, don't we? Yeah, I don't get that either.

Comment: I got it, We do not use them just to say something is not defined at some point. There is nothing special about those filled and empty circles, a filled circle reassures us about the value of the function is $y$ at that point, and an empty circle tells us $y$ at that point is *not* the value of the function. If we didn't use them, it was not clear that what is the value of the function at that certain $x$, because it is just the point that things can get *out of the nomal way*.

Comment: @Nick Notice how after a certain interval on the x-axis the function makes an instantaneous jump or 'step' -- hence the general term step function.

Comment: @Nick reading this may be helpful: http://msenux.redwoods.edu/IntAlgText/chapter2/section3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any graph, to find $f(x)$ you go to the value $x$ on the $x$ axis and then vertically to find $f(x)$.  In the first graph, if I asked you for $f(1.5)$, you would have not trouble reporting that $f(1.5)=1$.  If I asked for $f(1)$ and the dots were not there, you wouldn't know whether it is $0$ or $1$.  The filled dot is part of the graph and the open one is not, so $f(1)=1$.  This is the graph of the floor function, $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$, which means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  The others work the same way-when the vertical line looks like it intersects the graph twice, you look for the filled dot.

Comment: I cannot believe I had once asked such a silly question but I guess to anyone and everyone, new territory and notation would seem a bit daunting. Thank you for this answer :)